# Wrap 3rd party component in my component Using Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

Angular version is 16

I try to wrap 3rd party component in my component But I face problem when the wrraed component parent and child

For Example this tap component from angular material

```
<mat-tab-group>
     <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
     <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
     <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

how can wrap component like this in one component when I can't figur out how many child component and the content for child component shuld be render html content

Comment: I am very confused by your question. What is the 3rd party component you are trying to wrap inside of the mat-tab-group? If I am understanding it at all, you might want to look at content projection (https://angular.io/guide/content-projection). You can use one component as a wrapper and directly insert the desired contents to your child without having to figure out what to pass in through @Input().

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This sounds like you need a property on your component and generate the children dynamically based on those, instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you want to use [slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot) or [ng-content](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) for Angular.

Here's an example. Let's say I have a header where I want some fancy behaviors. But the header also needs a custom title each time depending on its context. I can use the `ng-content` feature to dynamically slot in the text.

Here's my header element.

```html
<h1 class="typebg {{primaryType}}" >
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <div class="icons-container">
    <div class="icons" [style.backgroundImage]="icon"></div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

You can see a lot of different UI components but the most important one is the `ng-content` where I will insert the actual title.

Now in another component I am able to pass in the text as a child:

```html
<typed-dialog-header *ngIf="pokemon" [type]="pokemon.type1">
  {{pokemon.species}}
</typed-dialog-header>
```

The text of the Pokémon's species is then inserted into the `ng-content`. I could put any sort of HTML component as a child to see it appear. If I had multiple slots, I could follow the linked guide above to give each slot specific names.